# How does AWS IAM Role rotate access keys, is it possible to configure it?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I launched EC2 instance with assigned IAM role.
I am able to retrieve the key.
As we can see, it has expiration time.

My application reads it once per 8-10 hours, so if key has been rotated app fails to write to S3.

How Amazon does rotate this temporary credentials?
Is it possible to configure or disable expiration time?
Purpose - we don't want to store credentials in source code.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no.

Furthermore, when launching an EC2 instance in an IAM role there is no reason, and you should not, attempt to use those generated keys directly.  The purpose of IAM role is allow your application to use AWS services for which the role is authorized without you having to deploy API keys to your application. That is the beauty and benefit of using IAM roles for EC2

Please refer to http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-roles-for-amazon-ec2.html

Answer (score 2):

No you cannot change this.

New credentials are made available no later than 5 minutes prior to the expiration of the previous ones - if you are close to the expiration time then you should start checking for new credentials and start using them.

Comment: Perhaps OP has overlooked the fact that the `"Expiration"` time of the credentials, in UTC, is provided with the response when the credentials are fetched.

Comment: That is why I created this question - I can see expiration time, and we wanted to change it. As I can see now, application have to take this responsibility. But what about the time? From our experience, key rotates every 5 hours. If you have some experience with it, can you share with us, please?